# Putnam 1986 question

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

$$PUTNAM,1986, QUESTION:B1$$
Inscribe a rectangle of base $b$ and height $h$ and an isosceles triangle of base $b$ in a circle of radius 1. For what value of $h$ do the rectangle and triangle have the same area.

I think it is a simple problem(in context of others), and I have solved it but I am looking for alternate solutions.

My solution:
Make a similar isosceles triangle on the other side $b$ of the rectangle.
If we see the line joining the apex of each isosceles triangle,it is divided in the ratio $ 2:1:2 $ by the side $b$.

This line segment is also the diameter and hence we get $h=\frac25$

Comment: I don't understand. The problem is trivial (by Putnam standards). You correctly give the obvious (and extrremely short) solution. Do you want a cumbersome solution, or are you expecting something even shorter? Incidentally, the original question states that the triangle and chord are on opposite sides of the chord, and you have assumed that in your solution.